# What are some of earliest examples of independent journalism?

Tags: journalism

While reading about [journalism on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journalism), I realized that the history section of the topic has accounts from as early as the 16th century, as quoted below from [antiquity section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journalism#History)

> Similar publications were established in the Republic of Venice in the 16th century

Similarly reading according to [Editors Guild of India](https://editorsguild.in/), the history of journalism in India started in 1780 as mentioned in their [history section](https://editorsguild.in/history-of-journalism/)

> The first newspaper in India is credited to James Augustus Hickey, who launched The Bengal Gazette, also the Calcutta General Advertiser, in 1780.

I couldn't find any reference of independent journalism in ancient history, the Wikipedia page does refer to "Dibao", which belongs to 206 BCE but it was published by the dynasty hence couldn't find anything related to independent journalism.

Did any society/civilisation in ancient history around the world had any kind or form of independent journalism, if yes, what were they?

Comment: This is basically going to go back to the start of the printing press. "Journalism" wasn't really possible without printing, while whoever owned a press got to pick and choose what information got mass-printed.

Comment: @MCW rephrased the question for more clarity

Comment: @T.E.D. well mass journalism on a very large scale might not be possible without a printing press, but it's not possible at all, I'm assuming just like the king had officers & employees to take their word to every village/town/city/capital they governed, there is a possibility of the existence of some folks who could spread the news and happenings from one corner of the empire to other

Comment: I'm skeptical; until the modern era it has been difficult to establish non-state entities.  And prior to widespread literacy, who would read independent journalism?

Comment: Does troubadours writing and singing about recent issues count as independent journalists?

Comment: Who paid the troubadour? I suspect most of them made their living singing at court, which would make them *very* dependent journalism.

Comment: Anybody who was travelling also spread news: merchants, soldiers, manual workers, people visiting relatives etc, probably since ancient times. Much of it wasn't written and it was hard to know what was fact and what was rumours, but marketplaces were not just for goods but also for hearing news. This was "independent" in the sense that it wasn't anything official and authorities had not much control over gossip on the market.

Comment: I forgot pilgrims, probably the biggest group of travelers. Of course this is still happening. Stay in any hostel and in the common rooms you hear a lot of news and information about other places that you don't get from journalistic media.

Comment: But is that journalism, or is it gossip?

Comment: @MCW What is journalism? In what way are today's tabloid papers or certain TV "news" stations different from gossip?  The key here is to define what the OP means by journalism. I could think of at least three different definitions.

Comment: The [history of Media](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_(region)#History) makes no mention of journalism. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The earliest proto newspaper in Europe might be what you are looking for?

In ancient Rome there were the *[Acta Diurna,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acta_Diurna)* (also *Acta urbis* or *populi diurna acta),* daily news propagated on the forum, as white wash boards, chiseled in stone, copied to papyri. The latter also distributed into the provinces. This was even more true for the weekly *Commentarius Rerum Novarum.*

This was of course centrally planned, initially, for example under strict instructions from Julius Caesar. But the "independent" part comes in when you see how the publications expanded. The governmental 'official news' were supplemented with curious events, gossip and 'yellow stuff' by the copyists and distributors.

The site ["Professional Journalsism"](https://teamwork09.wordpress.com/katie/) claims to have a (very rare) picture of a papyrus version of one issue of  *Acta diurna*

[image]

This picture needs some salt to go with it, as modern scholarship concurs with the [old Britannica entry:](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/1911_Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica/Acta_Diurna)

> Its contents were partly official (court news, decrees of the emperor, senate and magistrates), partly private (notices of births, marriages and deaths). Thus to some extent it filled the place of the modern newspaper (q.v.). The origin of the Acta is attributed to Julius Caesar, who first ordered the keeping and publishing of the acts of the people by public officers (59 B.C.; Suetonius, Caesar, 20). The Acta were drawn up from day to day, and exposed in a public place on a whitened board (see Album). After remaining there for a reasonable time they were taken down and preserved with other public documents, so that they might be available for purposes of research. The Acta differed from the Annals (which were discontinued in 133 B.C.) in that only the greater and more important matters were given in the latter, while in the former things of less note were recorded. Their publication continued till the transference of the seat of the empire to Constantinople. There are no genuine fragments extant.

Comment: I'm not sure *I'd* call that independent journalism.  IF the "yellow stuff" had included anything critical of the administration, I'm pretty sure that the administration would have exercised a veto.  "independent journalism" doesn't mean "journalism that successfully avoids state attention"

Comment: @MCW Sure. Not a 'censor' veto before publication, but 'consequences' for wrong doing? It hinges on definitions. What is meant with "independent".  Here, I just assumed 'not dictated directly by the chiefs' of whatever. Acta were not published entirely by 'the dynasty' only for 'bureaucrats' etc. Clarifications by QP for these definitions pending, I might have to expand this further, or just delete it. I still consider this one example within the framing(ancient)  I take away from the question.

Comment: @MCW The OP did not ask what defines the history of the Western world.